# Курсы валют из Cbr

Tags: php

В этом списке валют из cbr http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp отсутствует Тунисский динар (TND), как мне его получить? нужно относительно рубля

Comment: считать кросс-курс через доллар из других источников

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться другими источниками, например, Yahoo:

```js
const xchg = function(from, to) {
  return fetch(`http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22${from}${to}%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys`)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(xml => new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml'));
};

xchg('TND', 'RUB')
  .then(doc => doc.getElementsByTagName('Rate')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
  .then(rate => console.log(rate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Если посмотреть справочник по кодам валют, так там вообще нет Тунисского динара (TND)

> Справочник по кодам валют: [www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_val.asp?d=0](http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_val.asp?d=0)    ([XML_valFull.asp](http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_valFull.asp) список включающий ISO коды валют)
>
> ```
> d=0 Коды валют устанавливаемые ежедневно.
> d=1 Коды валют устанавливаемые ежемесячно.
> ```

[Источник](http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/Root.asp?PrtId=SXML)

Но если посмотреть котировки валют устанавливаемые ежемесячно - он там есть:

> [www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=02/03/2002&d=1](http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=22/03/2017&d=1) -
>   котировки валют устанавливаемые ежемесячно (устарело).

Все зависит от параметра `d`. Если он равен `1` - Тунисский динара (TND) будут, но нужно подобрать дату. Но метод как указано выше в описании устарел, так что скорее всего он не поддерживается.

Comment: Да это я заметил, но если дату поменять на 2010 и выше и d=1, то курсы не отображаются вовсе